# Unity 2017.3: transform.position assign attempt is not valid. Input position is { -infinity, 0,0 }

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I've been trying to build a raycast controller for a 2D game, and have followed some tutorial series to help me better understand how this is done. So far everything has been going well, and I've actually followed several tutorials on this topic to completion without issue.

However, while using this current character controller I am getting a slew of errors on play, even with no compiler errors present. I have never seen this error, and have not been able to find a solution online about how to fix it. Basically my character disappears on play (I assume its being moved infinitely to the left).

I get two errors: "transform.position assign attempt is not valid. Input position is { -infinity, 0,0 }," and "Invalid world AABB. Object is too large or too far away from origin."

The error occurs on lines 90:

```
public void LateUpdate()
{
Move(Velocity * Time.deltaTime); 
}
```

and 126:

```
characterTransform.Translate(deltaMovement, Space.World);
```

I have tried a bunch of different things, including changing my character's scale, changing Vector2s to Vector3s, removing Space.World, and calling transform.Translate directly (as opposed to using my characterTransform). Nothing seems to work, and for some reason my camera gives me an error sometimes too, though it is hard to reproduce. If I remove either line of code I get no errors, but obviously my character cannot move.

Screenshot of the errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGaz3.jpg

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
/// <summary>
/// Handles the character movement with raycasts
/// </summary>
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour {

//Defines the number of rays
private const int totalHorizontalRays = 8;
private const int totalVeritcalRays = 4;

private RaycastOrigins raycastOrigins; //References the RayCastOrigins struct

private const float skinWidth = .02f; //Defines the skin width of the rays, which places the origin point of the rays slightly inside the character's box collider

private static readonly float slopeLimitTanget = Mathf.Tan(75f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

public LayerMask platformMask; //Defines the layermask that will be used to determine how different layers interact with the character

public ControllerParameters2D defaultParameters; //References the ControllerParameters2D class

public ControllerState2D State { get; private set; } //References the ControllerState2D class
public ControllerParameters2D Parameters { get { return overrideParameters ?? defaultParameters; } } //Returns updated parameters, or default parameters if overrideParameters is null
public Vector2 Velocity { get { return velocity; } } //Defines the character's velocity
public bool CanJump { get { return false; } } //Defines whether or not the character can jump
public bool HandleCollisions { get; set; } //Defines whether or not the character needs to handle collisions (because it is colliding with something)

private Vector2 velocity; //The field for the Velocity property

private BoxCollider2D boxCollider; //References the box collider on the character
private ControllerParameters2D overrideParameters; //References the updated parameters (that is, the updated parameters, not the default ones)
private Transform characterTransform; //References the character's transform
private Vector3 localScale; //References the character's scale

//The distance between raycasts
private float horizontalDistanceBetweenRays;
private float verticalDistanceBetweenRays;

private struct RaycastOrigins //Stores the value types that define where the raycasts are created on the box collider
{
    public Vector2 topLeft, topRight; //Creates variables to define the upper position of the raycasts
    public Vector2 bottomLeft, bottomRight; //Creates variables to define the lower position of the raycasts
}

public void Awake()
{
    State = new ControllerState2D(); //Accesses the ControllerState2D script
    boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>(); //Accesses the character's box collider
    characterTransform = transform; //Accesses the character's transform
    localScale = transform.localScale; //Accesses the character's scale

    //Gets the ray spacing
    horizontalDistanceBetweenRays = CalculateHorizontalRaySpacing();
    verticalDistanceBetweenRays = CalculateVerticalRaySpacing();
}

public void Start()
{

}

public void AddForce(Vector2 force)
{
    velocity += force;
}

public void SetForce(Vector2 force)
{
    velocity = force;
}

public void SetHorizontalForce(float x)
{
    velocity.x = x;
}

public void SetVerticalForce(float y)
{
    velocity.y = y;
}

public void Jump()
{

}

public void LateUpdate()
{
    Move(Velocity * Time.deltaTime); //Moves the character per its velocity, scaled by time
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

}

public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{

}

private void Move(Vector2 deltaMovement)
{
    var wasGrounded = State.IsCollidingBelow; //Keeps track of whether or not the character is grounded
    State.Reset(); //Resets the state

    if (HandleCollisions) //If the character should handle collisions
    {
        HandlePlatforms();
        CalculateRaycastOrigins();

        if (deltaMovement.y < 0 && wasGrounded) //If the character is moving down, and was previously grounded...
        {
            ClimbDownSlope(ref deltaMovement);
        }

        if (Mathf.Abs(deltaMovement.x) > .001f) //If the character is moving left or right...
        {
            MoveHorizontally(ref deltaMovement);
        }

        MoveVertically(ref deltaMovement); //Calls the MoveVertically method always, since the character always has the force of gravity enacted on it
    }

    characterTransform.Translate(deltaMovement, Space.World); //Moves the character after all potential movement scenarios have been accounted for

    if (Time.deltaTime > 0)
    {
        velocity = deltaMovement / Time.deltaTime; //Sets the current velocity equal to the change in movement
    }

    //Clamps the velocity to the maximum x and y velocity defined in Parameters
    velocity.x = Mathf.Min(velocity.x, Parameters.maxVelocity.x);
    velocity.y = Mathf.Min(velocity.y, Parameters.maxVelocity.y);

    if (State.IsMovingUpSlope) //If the character is moving up a slope...
    {
        velocity.y = 0;
    }
}

private void MoveHorizontally(ref Vector2 deltaMovement)
{
    var isGoingRight = deltaMovement.x > 0; //Defines if the character is going right
    var rayDistance = Mathf.Abs(deltaMovement.x) + skinWidth; //Defines the distance of the raycasts
    var rayDirection = isGoingRight ? Vector2.right : -Vector2.right; //Defines in which direction the rays will shoot, depdending on character direction
    var rayOrigin = isGoingRight ? raycastOrigins.bottomRight : raycastOrigins.bottomLeft; //Defines the current ray origin

    for (var i = 0; i < totalHorizontalRays; i++) //Loops through each of the 8 horizontal rays
    {
        var rayVector = new Vector2(rayOrigin.x, rayOrigin.y + (i * verticalDistanceBetweenRays)); //Builds the rays (stacking them up with each ray that is added)
        Debug.DrawRay(rayVector, rayDirection * rayDistance, Color.red);

        var rayCastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayVector, rayDirection, rayDistance, platformMask); //Actually draws the rays

        if (!rayCastHit) //If the raycast hits something... (rayCastHit is true)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (i == 0 && ClimbUpSlope(ref deltaMovement, Vector2.Angle(rayCastHit.normal, Vector2.up), isGoingRight)) //If the character is now climbing a slope...
        {
            break;
        }

        deltaMovement.x = rayCastHit.point.x - rayVector.x; //Clamps horizontal movement based on ray collision
        rayDistance = Mathf.Abs(deltaMovement.x); //Clamps the ray distance based on how far the character is allowed to move (i.e. ensures the rays end at walls)

        if (isGoingRight) //If the character is going right...
        {
            deltaMovement.x -= skinWidth; //Ensures that the character moves with the correct value (otherwise would be able to move slightly more based on skinWidth value)
            State.IsCollidingRight = true;
        }

        else //If the character is going left...
        {
            deltaMovement.x += skinWidth;
            State.IsCollidingLeft = true;
        }

        if (rayDistance < skinWidth + .0001f) //If a collision gets bugged for some reason...
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}

private void MoveVertically(ref Vector2 deltaMovement)
{

}

private void ClimbDownSlope(ref Vector2 deltaMovement)
{

}

private bool ClimbUpSlope(ref Vector2 deltaMovement, float angle, bool isGoingRight)
{
    return false;
}

private void HandlePlatforms()
{

}

private float CalculateHorizontalRaySpacing()
{
    Bounds bounds = boxCollider.bounds; //Sets the 'bounds' variable equal to the bounds of the box collider on the game object
    bounds.Expand(skinWidth * -2); //Enforces the skinWidth variable

    return bounds.size.y / (totalHorizontalRays - 1); //Ensures that all rays are spaced evenly on the sides of the box collider
}

private float CalculateVerticalRaySpacing()
{
    Bounds bounds = boxCollider.bounds; //Sets the 'bounds' variable equal to the bounds of the box collider on the game object
    bounds.Expand(skinWidth * -2); //Enforces the skinWidth variable

    return bounds.size.x / (totalVeritcalRays - 1); //Ensures that all rays are spaced evenly on the bottom and top of the box collider
}

private void CalculateRaycastOrigins()
{
    Bounds bounds = boxCollider.bounds; //Sets the 'bounds' variable equal to the bounds of the box collider on the game object
    bounds.Expand(skinWidth * -2); //Enforces the skinWidth variable

    //Creates the starting positions of the raycasts
    raycastOrigins.bottomLeft = new Vector2(bounds.min.x, bounds.min.y);
    raycastOrigins.bottomRight = new Vector2(bounds.max.x, bounds.min.y);
    raycastOrigins.topLeft = new Vector2(bounds.min.x, bounds.max.y);
    raycastOrigins.topRight = new Vector2(bounds.max.x, bounds.max.y);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, it seems this is a bug that can sometimes occur.

Not sure why I didn't try this sooner, but reinstalling Unity fixed all the issues...